# FIWARE catalogue API for abstracting data plane information in FIWARE

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am working on this architecture:

[image]

At the moment, I receive sensor data in the CrateDB-based persistence which can be visualized in Grafana. However, I would like to expose the data persisted in CrateDB to the outside of the cluster via an API, so that the data can be consumed.

I have seen options like [Perseo](https://fiware-perseo-fe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with a focus on real-time scenarios. However, I have not found a project from the **FIWARE catalogue** that fits. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [STH Comet](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet/) (within the [Core Data Connectors](https://github.com/FIWARE/catalogue#core-data-connectors) section in FIWARE Catalogue) instead of CrateDB for that purpose.

It provides an API to get [raw historical information](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet/blob/master/doc/manuals/raw-data-retrieval.md) and also an API to get [aggregated historical information](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet/blob/master/doc/manuals/aggregated-data-retrieval.md), both REST-based.

Comment: Since STH Comet uses an NGSIv1 interface, is there any additional option to use the NGSIv2 specification? Thanks !!!

Comment: That's not fully correct... STH supports NGSIv2. Please, look carefully the above documents. You will find URLs including `v2`, which correspond to NGSIv2. The ones with `v1` are deprecated.